# Why do i get wrong values when i multiply a int by a double?

Tags: c++, math

Well, i am trying to do some basic operations in my program, such as subtraction and multiplication ...
i defined "get" and set methods for my classes  .... but when i applied the multuplication operation to a double and an int, i get values like: 1.7e-3.17 ....

here is my code:
is in spanish but ... i am sure you will understand

MAIN:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Tienda.h"
#define numeroClientes 2
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Cliente arregloClientes[numeroClientes];
string name;
int day, amount,i;
Tienda tienda = Tienda();


for(i=0; i<numeroClientes; i++){
system("cls");
cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del cliente: ";
cin>>name;
arregloClientes[i].setNombre(name);
cout<<"Ingerese numero de garrafones: ";
cin>>amount;
arregloClientes[i].setNumeroGarrafones(amount);
cout<<"Ingrese el dia de la compra"<<endl;
cout<<"0; Lunes 1; Martes 2; Miercoles 3; Jueves 4; Viernes: ";
cin>>day;
arregloClientes[i].setDia(day);
}

//Calculo del monto a pagar
for(i=0; i<numeroClientes; i++){
tienda.calcular(arregloClientes[i]);       
}

system("cls");
//Impresion de los datos
for(i=0; i<numeroClientes; i++){
cout<<"------------------------"<<endl;
arregloClientes[i].imprimir();       
}
cout<<"------------------------"<<endl;
tienda.imprimir();

cout<<"\n\n";
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

```
class Cliente {

  /* Atributos privados */
  private:
    string nombre;
    int numeroGarrafones;
    int dia; // 1 - 5 
    double totalCancelar;

    /* Metodos publicos */
    public:

     string getNombre();
     int getNumeroGarrafones();
     int getDia();         
     double getTotalCancelar();
     void setNombre(string nomb);
     void setNumeroGarrafones(int nG);
     void setDia(int d);
     void setTotalCancelar(double tC);
     void imprimir();
     string imprimirDia();

  }; // fin de clase Cliente
```

The problem is here:

```
void Tienda::calcular(Cliente persona){
 double aux,total;
  int garrafones= persona.getNumeroGarrafones();;

arregloDias[persona.getDia()]=  arregloDias[persona.getDia()] +                     persona.getNumeroGarrafones(); 

aux = garrafones * precioVenta - garrafones * precioCosto;                   

ganancia = ganancia + aux;

total = garrafones * precioVenta;

persona.setTotalCancelar(total);

 } // fin de calcular

 This one: 
aux = garrafones * precioVenta - garrafones * precioCosto;
```

The operation multiply ... generated numbers as i said before

anyone knows what happen ?

Comment: You probably forgot to initialize. Make sure the variables you are doing operations on are initialized to some value

Comment: I'm sure you can reproduce the problem in a simple, self-contained program. If you do that, and post it with sensible indentation and formatting, someone's more likely to read it.

Comment: put a breakpoint on that line and check what the values of 'aux', 'garrafones', 'precioVenta', and'precioCosto' are, that should help you work out what is going on.

Comment: Where's precioVenta come from? what's the implementation of Cliente.setNumeroGarrafones and Cliente.getNumeroGarrafones ? You might want to step through in a debugger and see at what point the different variables are not what you expect...

Comment: My answer makes essentially the same point Eammon makes.  If are not comfortable using a debugger you should invest some time learning how to as it will save you a lot of time.  However, for now, you can also perform the check also with a simple printf statement.  I agree that you should have tried to pinpoint where your code comes up with unexpected results: this would have probably helped you find the problem yourself.  Please keep this in mind for your next question.  One last remark, or rather a personal confession: I loved getting to  read code in Spanish! Brought back good memories :-)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment to my answer. How do you get the value of aux? The following code prints out 2, as it should. int garrafones = 5; double precioVenta = 2.5; double precioCosto = 2.1; double aux = garrafones * precioVenta - garrafones * precioCosto; printf("%.6g", aux);

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is an int * double problem, but an unitialised member problem.

Go to the line of interest:

```
aux = garrafones * precioVenta - garrafones * precioCosto;
```

Before that line, add the code: (or use your trusted debugger if you know how to set breakpoints and check  expressionvalues)

printf("--> %d %.6g  %.6g\n", garrafones, precioVenta, precioCosto);

I believe that you will probably find that member instances of your Tienda object are unitialised and contain "random" values.

Comment: This is the constructor of Tienda class:
Tienda::Tienda(void){
 precioVenta=2.5;
 precioCosto=2.1;
 ganancia = 0;
       for(int i=0; i<numeroDias; i++){
       arregloDias[i]=0;    
        }             
}

But now my new value is 0 not a rare like 1.06e2586 .....

so ... i do not what to do ...

Comment: "But now my new value is 0 not a rare like 1.06e2586 ..... so ... "  Sorry I did not understand.  Could you please give some more details?  You say "now".  Does this mean you have changed something?  What are the values of aux, garrafones, precioVenta, and precioCosto that you get from the printf or your debugger?

Comment: For two clients i got this:
i used the printf function  before operated the variables...
--> 5  2.5 2.1 
--> 6 2.5 2.1 

it seems that everything is ok with the initialisations...

Comment: @KevinRivera I tried the following:
 int garrafones = 5;
 double precioVenta = 2.5;
 double precioCosto = 2.1;
 double aux = garrafones * precioVenta - garrafones * precioCosto;
 printf("%.6g", aux); and got 2.  Are you saying you are getting 0?

Answer (score 0):

The only moment you're using "tienda" before calculating is when you call the constructor. You should check if you're initializing precioVenta and precioCosto in that constructor, i guess those are fixed values and belong to the "Tienda" class in case those are not global variables (and in that case you should initialize it anyway).